# Abelian Group Question: Why is $e^n e^m = e$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $G$ be an abelian group. Let $x,y \in G$. Let $m,n$ be positive integers. Assume that $x^m=e=y^n$. Prove that $(xy)^{mn}=e$ also.

So what I have done is:

$$
(xy)^{mn} = x^{mn} y^{mn} = (x^m)^n (y^n)^m = e^n e^m
$$

How does $e^n e^m$ become $e$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The identity times anything is itself (so the identity times the identity is the identity again), so $e^m = \underbrace{e\cdot e\cdot\ldots\cdot e}_{m\textrm{ times}}$, which is just $e$ (you can show this rigorously by induction).

> $k = 1$: $e^1 = e$, so we're done. Now suppose $e^k = e$ for some $k\in\Bbb{N}$. We will show that $e^{k + 1} = e$. $e^{k + 1} = e^k e = e\cdot e = e$ (by the definition of the identity), so $e^k = e$ for all $k\in\Bbb{N}$. (You can do the same in the negative direction to show that this holds for all $k\in\Bbb{Z}$.)

Answer (score 4):

$e$ is the unit in the group, so $ez=z$ for all $z$.  In particular, $ee=e^2=e$.